# extending iOS Phonegap build with WatchKit Extension - Cordova/CDV.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, watchkit

I have an iOS app that I created by using Phonegapp. I can open it with Xcode and build it with no errors.
So, now I want to extend it with the WatchKit. I want a watch app and this Phonegapp iOS app to cummunicate. So I add a WatchKit as a target.
But now the build fails: Cordova/CDV.h file not found (in Bridging Header)

I read many articles about this problem, but none could solve my problem. I let the import command "#import " point to the file directly via "../CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDV.h" which solves this problem. But then I have some Segmentation fault 11 errors.

Has anybody experience with that kind of problem? Can it be that it's because I don't have a provisioning profile? I have an apple account but I'm not yet an "developer", so don't pay anything yet.

/Users/iflx/Documents/phoneGap/myAPP/platforms/ios/myapp/Bridging-Header.h:28:9: error: 'Cordova/CDV.h' file not found #import  ^ :0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/iflx/Documents/phoneGap/myApp/platforms/ios/myapp/Bridging-Header.h'

the location of the CDV.h file is "CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDV.h".

If I change the import command then it builds and causes Segmentation fault 11 errors: /Users/iflx/Documents/phoneGap/myApp/platforms/ios/myapp/Bridging-Header.h:28:9: note: in file included from /Users/iflx/Documents/phoneGap/myAPP/platforms/ios/myapp/Bridging-Header.h:28: #import "../CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDV.h" ^

... and many more like this for CDVDelegate.h too

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's kinda hard to spot any errors...

Comment: thx for reply, added the error code. i read in other articles that it may happen cause of missing provisioning profile, possible? because ... I didn't change anything in the code yet. just added watchios target to phonegap ios project

Answer (score 3):

Deleting or commenting the "#import Cordova/CDV.h" row helped